# How to program multiple processor cores?

Tags: multithreading, processors

I want to program some processor cores to perform a task in a way defined by me.
How to do that? 
How can i write a program to do so? can this work for me or not

```
BOOL SetProcessAffinityMask( HANDLE hProcess, DWORD_PTR dwProcessAffinityMask);
```

Am I required to do assembly language programming or something?
If yes, then how?

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The typical approach is to spawn one thread for each core you want to use, and have each thread do a sub-portion of the total work load, and let the OS's thread-scheduler handle the assignment of threads to cores automatically for you.  No assembly language is usually required, just use of a threading API (which will vary depending on which language you are programming in, but is typically either pthreads or a thread class)

Comment: Oh Thanks Jeremy this seems to be helpful

Comment: and if you can help me understanding that how set affinity logic works?

Comment: Setting a thread's affinity simply tells the OS's CPU scheduler that that particular thread should only run on a particular CPU, rather than on whichever CPU happens to be available at any given moment.  I can't go into any more detail than that because I don't know any details about your environment (i.e. which OS you are using, or which programming language)

Comment: I'm using windows 10

Comment: i want to know that what is the code behind set affinity working?
I want to create one.

Comment: This is probably the function you want (I've never used it myself so I can't say much more than that):  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadaffinitymask